# System.Configuration.Install in .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, service, .net-6.0

I have a WiX installer and I am looking to move to WiX Toolset 4 using .NET 6.0.  Some of the apps we install are written in .NET Framework and there are some Windows Services in there I need to install.  I am currently using System.Configuration.Install with the ServiceProcessInstaller class to install/uninstall my services.

If my installer code is in .NET 6.0, is there still a way to install a service using code?  I would rather not use sc.exe if it can be helped.  We used to do it that way and the ServiceProcessInstaller works much better.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe all I needed was the TopShelf.ServiceInstaller package.  I forgot I have used this in the past.

Comment: I've a similar issue, do you mind providing a bit more information on what do you mean by a `TopShelf.ServiceInstaller` package ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the wix toolset  and  in the Product.wxs file. Following is a snippet. For the detail you can reference my github repo [enter link description here](https://github.com/newonejoe/WixTutorial/blob/master/WebMvcApp.Installer/Product.wxs)

```xml
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
            <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
                <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
            <!-- </Component> -->
             <!-- service registration-->
      <Component Id="ProductComponent">
        <File Id="WebMvcAppEXE" 
              Name="WebMvcApp.exe" 
              DiskId="1"
              Source="$(var.WebMvcApp.TargetDir)\WebMvcApp.exe"
              Vital="yes"
              KeyPath="yes"
              />
        <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                        Type="ownProcess"
                        Vital="yes"
                        Name ="WebMvcAppService"
                        DisplayName="WebMvcApp Windows Service"
                        Description="A windows service that host the Web Mvc App."
                        Start="auto"
                        Account="LocalSystem"
                        ErrorControl="normal"/>
        <ServiceControl Id="StartService" 
                        Start="install" 
                        Stop="both" 
                        Remove="uninstall" 
                        Name="WebMvcAppService" 
                        Wait="yes"/>
      </Component>

        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
```